# How to concatenate path with context-path in swagger?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(path = "/demo/test")
public Object demoService() {
    // something...
}
```

And I configured context-path in `application.yml`:

```yaml
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /provider
```

The default interface path generated by swagger is:

```
/demo/test
```

What I want is to concatenate the context-path with the interface path:

```
/provider/demo/test
```

I have tried to create swagger configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConf {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
               .pathMapping("provider")
               .select()
               .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
               .paths(PathSelectors.any())
               .build();
    }
}
```

This approach will generate exceptions：

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple Dockets with the same group name are not supported. The following duplicate groups were discovered. default
```

I don't want to set a new group name, I need it to take effect in the default group.
So, what should I do?